# Conditional Stylesheets Set-up: Using the Module

Tags: 7, theming

**Problem**

I'm trying to set-up conditional stylesheets. I've followed the instructions but it's still not registering. What have I done wrong?

**Set-Up**

I installed and enabled the conditional stylesheets module. I'm running a Tao sub-theme.

I then added the following lines to my theme.info file:

```
//these are my original stylesheets
stylesheets[all][] = reset.css
stylesheets[all][] = typography.css

//these are my conditional stylesheets
conditional-stylesheet [IE][all][] = styleie7.css
conditional-stylesheets [if !IE][all][] = style.css
```

I then cleared my cache and no style sheets were loaded.

At the moment I'm just trying to have one stylesheet for IE and one for everything else.

I took the syntax from the [link] in the conditional css directory.[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx#syntax)

NOTE:

It's not clear whether you should put

```
conditional-stylesheet OR stylesheet-conditional
```

The documentation says one, a lot of posts suggest the other. However I can't get either of them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the conditional style module the format would be

```
; Set the conditional stylesheets that are processed by IE.
stylesheets-conditional[lt IE 7][all][] = ie6-and-below.css
stylesheets-conditional[IE 9][all][] = ie9.css
stylesheets-conditional[IE][print][] = ie-print.css
stylesheets-conditional[(gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|(!IE)][all][] = modern-browsers.css
```

And there should be no space between the `conditional-stylesheet` and `[IE]`.

If that doesn't work then you should make sure that the stylesheet it is referencing can be loaded. The stylesheet lines don't show up if the stylesheet doesn't exist or cannot be opened.

Comment: Cheers, turns out how I had a couple problems. First was the space, the second was I was using putting in an `[if]`, which the module adds automatically so I had two `[if]'s`. Weirdly it also didn't work at all on my Windows 7 machine. I had to switch to XP.

Answer (score 0):

My final code in my .info file is:

```
stylesheets-conditional[!IE 6][all][] = typography.css
stylesheets-conditional[IE 6][all][] = typographyie6.css

stylesheets-conditional[IE 6][all][] = styleie6.css
stylesheets-conditional[IE 7][all][] = styleie7.css
```

I had three problems. First I had an extra space. Second I was putting `[if]` into the conditional statements i.e.

```
stylesheets-conditional[if IE 6][all][] = styleie6.css
```

The module already adds an `[if]` so it was printing out:

```
<!--[if if IE 7]>
 <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost/drupalie/sites/all/themes/mytheme/styleie7.css?mutp08");</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Lastly I couldn't get it work at all on my Windows 7 machine, but switching to XP worked fine.

IE6 & 7 don't work very well on Windows 7 (hacks needed...) so might be worth setting up an XP test machine as you wouldn't need them to work on 7 anyway.